# Vector integral in $N$ dimensions.

Tags: integration

In $N$ dimensions I want to do an integral of the flux through an $N-1$ dimensional surface. The usual vector calculus integration theorems help by allowing integration around the perimeter of the surface. But that perimeter is now $N-2$ dimensions. In $4D$ it could be a cube or a $2$-sphere. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed the same way as you did before. Usually, the divergence theorem suffices to calculate the flux of a vector field through a surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and is stated as:

In a compact $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with a piecewise smooth boundary $\partial V$ and a vector field $\vec F$ defined in a boundary of V,

$\int_{\partial V} \vec F \cdot \vec n$=$\int_{V} \nabla \cdot \vec F$